# How to scroll an ExpansionTile / Listview when a tile is expanded?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

We have a bunch of `ExpansionTile` within a `ListView` (so far not too crazy, right?).  Our users would like us to "auto scroll" the list when they open up an `ExpansionTile` so the new expanded tile is now at the top (or as top as it can be) of the screen so they don't have to manually scroll to see what we just opened.

I think we need something like a `ScrollController` on the `ListView` -- and to register an onExpansionChanged .. to do .. *something*.  It's the something that's more than a bit vague to me.  :)

Any pointers or help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

TIA!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I got right what your asking for, is basically a way to scroll automatically your `ExpansionTile` up so the user doesn't have to do it manually to see its content, right?

Then, you can actually use a `ScrollController` in your `ListView` and take advantage of the `onExpansionChanged` callback of the `ExpansionTile` to scroll it up/down accordingly to the size of the tile vs. its current position.

But now you are wondering: ***how do I know how much to scroll?***

For that, either you know previously how exactly is the height of your widget when constructing it by giving it some constraints (like building a `Container(heigh: 100.0))` or, in this particular scenario, you don't know exactly how many pixels the `ExpansionTile` height will take. So, we can use a `GlobalKey` and then check its rendering height by checking its `RenderBox` at runtime to know **exactly** how many pixels it's taking when collapsed and multiply it by its index.

```
  ExpansionTile _buildExpansionTile(int index) {
    final GlobalKey expansionTileKey = GlobalKey();
    double previousOffset;

    return ExpansionTile(
      key: expansionTileKey,
      onExpansionChanged: (isExpanded) {
        if (isExpanded) previousOffset = _scrollController.offset;
        _scrollToSelectedContent(isExpanded, previousOffset, index, expansionTileKey);
      },
      title: Text('My expansion tile $index'),
      children: _buildExpansionTileChildren(),
    );
  }
```

Ok, now we have a `ListView` that will use this  `_buildExpansionTile` in its generator with a `GlobalKey`. We are also saving the scroll offset of the `ListView` when we expand the tile. But, how do we actually scroll up to show its content? Let's see the `_scrollToSelectedContent` method.

```
  void _scrollToSelectedContent(bool isExpanded, double previousOffset, int index, GlobalKey myKey) {
    final keyContext = myKey.currentContext;

    if (keyContext != null) {
      // make sure that your widget is visible
      final box = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      _scrollController.animateTo(isExpanded ? (box.size.height * index) : previousOffset,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
    }
  }
```

So, we are accessing the render object by its key and then use the `ListView` scroll controller to scroll up when expanded and down back to its initial position when collapsed by multiplying its height with its index. You don't have to scroll back, it was just my personal preference for this example. This will result in something like this:

[image: example]

And here you have the full example in a `StatefulWidget`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  void _scrollToSelectedContent(bool isExpanded, double previousOffset, int index, GlobalKey myKey) {
    final keyContext = myKey.currentContext;

    if (keyContext != null) {
      // make sure that your widget is visible
      final box = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      _scrollController.animateTo(isExpanded ? (box.size.height * index) : previousOffset,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _buildExpansionTileChildren() => [
        FlutterLogo(
          size: 50.0,
        ),
        Text(
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vulputate arcu interdum lacus pulvinar aliquam. Donec ut nunc eleifend, volutpat tellus vel, volutpat libero. Vestibulum et eros lorem. Nam ut lacus sagittis, varius risus faucibus, lobortis arcu. Nullam tempor vehicula nibh et ornare. Etiam interdum tellus ut metus faucibus semper. Aliquam quis ullamcorper urna, non semper purus. Mauris luctus quam enim, ut ornare magna vestibulum vel. Donec consectetur, quam a mattis tincidunt, augue nisi bibendum est, quis viverra risus odio ac ligula. Nullam vitae urna malesuada magna imperdiet faucibus non et nunc. Integer magna nisi, dictum a tempus in, bibendum quis nisi. Aliquam imperdiet metus id metus rutrum scelerisque. Morbi at nisi nec risus accumsan tempus. Curabitur non sem sit amet tellus eleifend tincidunt. Pellentesque sed lacus orci.',
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        ),
      ];

  ExpansionTile _buildExpansionTile(int index) {
    final GlobalKey expansionTileKey = GlobalKey();
    double previousOffset;

    return ExpansionTile(
      key: expansionTileKey,
      onExpansionChanged: (isExpanded) {
        if (isExpanded) previousOffset = _scrollController.offset;
        _scrollToSelectedContent(isExpanded, previousOffset, index, expansionTileKey);
      },
      title: Text('My expansion tile $index'),
      children: _buildExpansionTileChildren(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyScrollView'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _buildExpansionTile(index),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG -- genius and to be honest, I **never** would have gotten that!  Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help. Just want to remind you that you may need to tweak it a little for the last items on the `ListView` if you also want the same behavior, since it can't scroll more because before the last `ExpansionTile` is expanded, there isn't more content to scroll. For that, you'll have to figure when the expansion is completed and then scroll the amount of its child height.

Comment: The answer gives a good starting point, however, there are few things to consider: 1) In case you expand one tile and then expand one more, the scroll position is not accurate anymore; 2) How to get notified in case the last item is expanded, and how to get its expanded height?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo Can we with this make expanded only one item?

Answer (score 7):

If you are still facing this issue, I found another solution using the Scrollable widget. Using a GlobalKey, we have to pass the current context of the ExpansionTile to the ensureVisible method of the Scrollable class and it'll do all the work.

For higher reusability, create an extension on GlobalKey:

```dart
extension GlobalKeyEnsureVisible on GlobalKey {
  void ensureVisible() {
    final keyContext = currentContext;
    if (keyContext != null) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200)).then((_) {
        Scrollable.ensureVisible(keyContext, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your Widget, declare a global key:

```dart
final expansionTileKey = GlobalKey();
```

And assign this global key to the expansion tile. Also, when the tile expands, call the ensureVisible() method we defined above.

```dart
ExpansionTile(
  key: expansionTileKey,
  onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
    if (expanded) expansionTileKey.ensureVisible();
  },
```

You can check my article [How to scroll an ExpansionTile when it is expanded?](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-how-to-scroll-an-expansiontile-when-it-is-expanded-ad706cfb80a6) for more info.

Comment: This is super simple, and has none of the bloated calculation of the other answers.

Comment: Wow, Just clean and elegant solution!

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138020/flutter-scroll-to-specific-item-in-list#answer-57138204) answer you can calculate how much is needed to scroll by getting the current scroll offset of ListView from its controller:

```
_scrollController.offset
```

and add it to the current ExpansionTile Y position given from its key:

```
RenderBox _box = _ExpansiontileKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
yPosition = _box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy;
```

This position considers the status bar and AppBar heights, so the scroll point can be calculated by:

```
scrollPoint = _scrollController.offset + yPosition - MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).padding.top - 56;
```

`MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).padding.top` will give you the statusbar height and from constats.dart you can get the AppBar height:

```
/// The height of the toolbar component of the [AppBar].
const double kToolbarHeight = 56.0;
```

You can avoid miscalculations of the last items by checking if the scrollPoint is below the maximum extent of the scroll:

```
if(_scrollPoint <= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
  _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollPoint, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
else
  _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
  );
```

**Notice** that ExpansionTiles own expansion animation takes 200ms like shown in its definition:
`const Duration _kExpand = Duration(milliseconds: 200);` therefore it is a good idea to wait for expansion animation to finish before starting scrolling so you can get the updated values.

One approach is to delay the the call using `Future.delayed(duration)`:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 250)).then((value){
  RenderBox _box = _ExpansiontileKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  yPosition = _box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy;
  scrollPoint = _scrollController.offset + yPosition - 
    MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).padding.top - 56;
    if(_scrollPoint <= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollPoint, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 
        500), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    else
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, 
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
  });
```

Other than that you can make your own ExpansionTile and give it whatever duration you want for expanding.