# Expansion panel at bottom page to automatically scroll up when expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Expanded Panel in a page.

```
ExpansionPanel(
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(Translations.of(context).text(title)),
    );
  },
  canTapOnHeader: true,
  body: _buildSection(context, icon, desc),
  isExpanded: _isExpanded[index]
)
```

The Expanded panel is at the below some other content in the page and collapse by default. When user click to expand the panel, it will expand but at the bottom of the screen which is not visible unless they scroll up.

Is there a way for the expanded panel to move up when user press to expand it if it's at the bottom of the page?

Comment: this question and answer may help you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829431/how-to-scroll-an-expansiontile-listview-when-a-tile-is-expanded