# ExpansionTile does not scroll to the content on open

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to scroll to the content of ExpansionTile on open? When `Delivery Information` is open the screen does not scroll to the tile content.

```
    ExpansionTile(
          title: Text(
            'Delivery Information',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          ),
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829431/how-to-scroll-an-expansiontile-listview-when-a-tile-is-expanded

Comment: @PeterKoltai I think it will do the job although I didn't try yet.