# Wants to show selected item in full screen view in flutter ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

In the 1st picture there are many ExpansionTiles in ListView. On selection it shows details. But when showing details, it does not show in full screen. If ExpansionTile is at the top then it is shown on the whole screen but for the ones at the bottom you have to scroll down and go further down (2nd picture).
I want to show the details in full screen when I select an ExpansionTile.
How to do? [ I want the selected item to be placed at top of the screen (without changing items order) ]
[image: Before selecting]
[image: After selecting]

Comment: I would try to use `onExpansionChanged` of `ExpansionTile` to detect when a tile is expanded, add a `ScrollController` to the `ListView`, and use the controller to position within the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll an ExpansionTile / Listview when a tile is expanded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829431/how-to-scroll-an-expansiontile-listview-when-a-tile-is-expanded)

Comment: @AdarshRaj Yes it does but its too complicated for beginner (lazy like me). I mean we don't want to go through RenderObject, PreviousOffset and many other complicated things. We just want something to scroll to the beginning of the selected item in easiest way.